# How to use Blowfish to encrypt password in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, blowfish

I want to know how to use blowfish algorithm to hash a password using salt in Node.js
the algorithm should be one way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the bcrypt module (It uses blowfish)

https://www.npmjs.org/package/bcrypt

note that the module handles combining the salt with the hash for you, so once the hash is generated you do not have to manage storing the salt (note that the compare function just needs the password, the salt is implicitly in the hash)

It is very straightforward(copy from the docs)

```
async (recommended)

To hash a password:

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("B4c0/\/", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
    });
});
To check a password:

// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare("B4c0/\/", hash, function(err, res) {
    // res == true
});
bcrypt.compare("not_bacon", hash, function(err, res) {
    // res = false
});
Auto-gen a salt and hash:

bcrypt.hash('bacon', 8, function(err, hash) {
});
```